# Best Way For ( Using Databases , Access DB , Login Authentification , USER )

Tags: database, authentication, cookies

I need to create a pretty complex website for my class and before I started, I wanted to get some input from more experienced coders if I'm on the right track.

Basically, when I go to the url: I get a simple login page, when a user logs in - he can view his profile and make schedules / save etc...

I read a bit online and this is how I decided to proceed (please let me know if there is a simpler way or an already-made code for these):

```
1 . Access phpmyAdmin - create db
2 . Create a php function to access the db (add users etc...)
3 . use a login form with a php function on the main page and authenticate user/pass by accessing the db
4 . Use cookies to keep user logged in.
```

I also need to keep several lists for each user like:

classes = (comp232 , comp348 , comp352.....)

Which is the best way to do this for each user:

DB, txt file, List, Arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'depends'. However, when you had mentioned that you want to develop a 'complex website', it deserves to have Database roundtrip :) whereas all the other options you had mentioned would be simple enough for a stand alone application.

To answer your other main question, yes, there are already built in solutions which you can make use of, if you don't want to write the application on your own. However, you may need to evaluate thoroughly whether it fits your bill, else you may end  up customising the application which is more or less half writing of the application by yourself.

If you want to write the application by your own, the PHP has got a built in APIs to achieve whatever you had mentioned. We have a great set of forums to get assistance wherever we are stuck.